# Replace flash with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, replace

I have next mission: i have to replace flash alement with javascript in this page: http://www.fplus.si/
(changing the images with buttons for every image)

Afcourse it has to look and work excactly the same. I found some jquery modules that do almost like this, but there are not the same. did somebody stumbled upon such module?

Thank for help, Peter

Comment: I think you could make much nicer buttons than they are at the moment... don't just make it the same, make it better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your client meant ***exactly the same***. You could go with some suitable carousel/lightbox control and use CSS to position those buttons correctly over the images.

But as far as I can see this is done purely by fading images on a predefined interval. No special functionality. It can be done without any particular control as well. As long as you have some client lib that implements animations.

position buttons using

```
position: relative;
top: -50px; /* as much as needed */
margin-left: 20px;
float: left;
```

and set their `:hover` state with different `background-image` CSS setting. But don't forget to put an additional empty `<div>` afterwards with CSS setting `clear: both`. To continue rest of the document as it was.

Answer (score 0):

If they need to be exactly the same you could grab the images for both states (normal and rollover) on the site and use those images in normal html+css and define a rollover state with the rollover image.
It can be as simple as that.

You can even choose to implement the rollover functionality with css or javascript.
Personally I prefer css because you can not 100% rely on javascript being activated at the client side.

Comment: What i dont know how to add buttons 1,2,3,4.... at the bottom of the picture...
Each button has its rollover state, so they have to be object of their own?